# Use regular ROS subscriptions on arduino (not rosserial_arduino)

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am wondering if there is any way to use 'regular' ROS subscriptions on an arduino, rather than the 'special' rosserial_arduino ones. There are some functions on the regular subscription classes that I want to use that are not available on the arduino ones.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50466/use-regular-ros-subscriptions-on-arduino-(not-rosserial_arduino)/) by [sgwhack](https://answers.ros.org/users/2844/sgwhack/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2012-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No. The roscpp library does not work on the Arduino for several reasons. The Arduino is (still) a very limited platform with an Atmel 8 bit controller and no ethernet connector. rosserial is basically just some kind of proxy that sends all messages the Arduino subscribed to through a serial line using a special protocol and the other way around. That's why its interface sort of looks like roscpp, but it actually is something completely different.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3